# Pymongo throws "KeyError: 'errmsg'" when attempting to connect to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using the following code to connect to mongo:

```
full = "mongodb+srv://myuser:mypass@hpechatops-dzlpw.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"
client = MongoClient(full)
db = client.admin

serverStatusResult=db.command("serverStatus")
pprint(serverStatusResult)
```

I receive this error:

```
errmsg - details["errmsg"]
KeyError: 'errmsg'
```

This doesn't really tell me much, so I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong. This code stems from tutorials such as this one https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb.

Comment: can you confirm admin database in client.database_names()

Comment: Put question mark `?` after database name that is `/test?retryWrites=true`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet That was just a typo in the question, edited question and fixed it. Code is still not working unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would check that. I'm following this guide: https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb which only has me install pymongo. You can  see the step I'm on based off my code, pretty early on. edit: I am using Atlas, as the guide states as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_host = "(enter the prefix).mlab.com"
mongo_port = (enter port number)
mongo_db = "(enter db name)"
mongo_user = "(enter username)"
mongo_pass = "(enter password)"
connection = MongoClient(mongo_host, mongo_port)
db = connection[mongo_db]
db.authenticate(mongo_user, mongo_pass)
```